# Manage to merge two arrays depending in two values inside the object

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, dictionary, logic

I am facing an issue while use map and conditionals, basically as seen on the example, I have two arrays of objects that I need to differenciate based on two properties from the object: location_id and location_id.

```js
const addedItems = [
  {
    "item_variation_id": "itemvar_QQWn8cQxq7TnB6",
    "quantity": 5,
    "location_id": "loc_r91C120vrwlReF",
    "current_stock": 0,
    "action": "add_stock",
  },
  {
    "item_variation_id": "itemvar_QQWn8cQxq7TnB6",
    "quantity": 8,
    "location_id": "loc_5MHY8nXyvSIqh2",
    "current_stock": -2,
    "action": "add_stock",
  },
  {
    "item_variation_id": "itemvar_QQWn8cQxq7TnB6",
    "quantity": 15,
    "location_id": "loc_5BpxGVWA9g09vf",
    "current_stock": 0,
    "action": "add_stock",
  }
];

const preItems = [
  {
    "item_variation_id": "itemvar_O49yq8yCDC2v1N",
    "quantity": null,
    "location_id": "loc_r91C120vrwlReF",
    "current_stock": 59,
    "action": "",
  },
  {
    "item_variation_id": "itemvar_O49yq8yCDC2v1N",
    "quantity": null,
    "location_id": "loc_5MHY8nXyvSIqh2",
    "current_stock": 8,
    "action": "",
  },
  {
    "item_variation_id": "itemvar_O49yq8yCDC2v1N",
    "quantity": null,
    "location_id": "loc_5BpxGVWA9g09vf",
    "current_stock": 1,
    "action": "",
  },
  {
    "item_variation_id": "itemvar_duW8Yhhd4aT1iF",
    "quantity": null,
    "location_id": "loc_r91C120vrwlReF",
    "current_stock": 27,
    "action": "",
  },
  {
    "item_variation_id": "itemvar_duW8Yhhd4aT1iF",
    "quantity": null,
    "location_id": "loc_5MHY8nXyvSIqh2",
    "current_stock": 0,
    "action": "",
  },
  {
    "item_variation_id": "itemvar_duW8Yhhd4aT1iF",
    "quantity": null,
    "location_id": "loc_5BpxGVWA9g09vf",
    "current_stock": -4,
    "action": "",
  },
  {
    "item_variation_id": "itemvar_QQWn8cQxq7TnB6",
    "quantity": 5,
    "location_id": "loc_r91C120vrwlReF",
    "current_stock": 0,
    "action": "add_stock",
  },
  {
    "item_variation_id": "itemvar_QQWn8cQxq7TnB6",
    "quantity": null,
    "location_id": "loc_5MHY8nXyvSIqh2",
    "current_stock": -2,
    "action": "",
  },
  {
    "item_variation_id": "itemvar_QQWn8cQxq7TnB6",
    "quantity": null,
    "location_id": "loc_5BpxGVWA9g09vf",
    "current_stock": 0,
    "action": "",
  },
  {
    "item_variation_id": "itemvar_YASfOt2B6B4ixE",
    "quantity": null,
    "location_id": "loc_r91C120vrwlReF",
    "current_stock": 0,
    "action": "",
  }
]

const findItem = (id) => addedItems.find( itemData => itemData.item_variation_id === id )

const updatedItems = [...preItems.map( item => 
( item.item_variation_id === findItem(item.item_variation_id)?.item_variation_id && 
  item.location_id === findItem(item.item_variation_id)?.location_id 
) ? findItem(item.item_variation_id) : item
)  ]

console.log(updatedItems)
```

In summary, what I want to get is,

```
first: compare the two arrays (addeedItems and preItems)
second: match these keys while iterating: item_variation_id and location_id
third: if those two match values(item_variation_id and location_id) matches while iterating, remove the item from preItem and add the item from addedItems
```

To conclude, my function updatedItems only removes one item, and the output expected should move 3 items. So output will be that 3 values will be updated with their respective quantity

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: `if those two match, remove the item from preItem and add the item from addedItems` this requirement is not clear

Comment: Basically if item_variation_id and location_id match, I need to move the item from preItems and add the item from addeedItems to preItems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just map the preItems array and in each iteration test the addedItems array for the match. If it's there, return the addeditems match, otherwise return the preItems match. There are a few ways to do this. I used `array.prototype.find`

```
let updated = preItems.map(p => {
      let b = addedItems.find(a => a.location_id === p.location_id && a.item_variation_id === p.item_variation_id);
      return b ? b : p;
    });
```

```js
const addedItems = [{
    "item_variation_id": "itemvar_QQWn8cQxq7TnB6",
    "quantity": 5,
    "location_id": "loc_r91C120vrwlReF",
    "current_stock": 0,
    "action": "add_stock",
    "xtra": " ADDED1!!!"
  },
  {
    "item_variation_id": "itemvar_QQWn8cQxq7TnB6",
    "quantity": 8,
    "location_id": "loc_5MHY8nXyvSIqh2",
    "current_stock": -2,
    "action": "add_stock",
    "xtra": " ADDED2!!!"
  },
  {
    "item_variation_id": "itemvar_QQWn8cQxq7TnB6",
    "quantity": 15,
    "location_id": "loc_5BpxGVWA9g09vf",
    "current_stock": 0,
    "action": "add_stock",
    "xtra": " ADDED3!!!"
  }
];

const preItems = [{
    "item_variation_id": "itemvar_O49yq8yCDC2v1N",
    "quantity": null,
    "location_id": "loc_r91C120vrwlReF",
    "current_stock": 59,
    "action": "",
  },
  {
    "item_variation_id": "itemvar_O49yq8yCDC2v1N",
    "quantity": null,
    "location_id": "loc_5MHY8nXyvSIqh2",
    "current_stock": 8,
    "action": "",
  },
  {
    "item_variation_id": "itemvar_O49yq8yCDC2v1N",
    "quantity": null,
    "location_id": "loc_5BpxGVWA9g09vf",
    "current_stock": 1,
    "action": "",
  },
  {
    "item_variation_id": "itemvar_duW8Yhhd4aT1iF",
    "quantity": null,
    "location_id": "loc_r91C120vrwlReF",
    "current_stock": 27,
    "action": "",
  },
  {
    "item_variation_id": "itemvar_duW8Yhhd4aT1iF",
    "quantity": null,
    "location_id": "loc_5MHY8nXyvSIqh2",
    "current_stock": 0,
    "action": "",
  },
  {
    "item_variation_id": "itemvar_duW8Yhhd4aT1iF",
    "quantity": null,
    "location_id": "loc_5BpxGVWA9g09vf",
    "current_stock": -4,
    "action": "",
  },
  {
    "item_variation_id": "itemvar_QQWn8cQxq7TnB6",
    "quantity": 5,
    "location_id": "loc_r91C120vrwlReF",
    "current_stock": 0,
    "action": "add_stock",
  },
  {
    "item_variation_id": "itemvar_QQWn8cQxq7TnB6",
    "quantity": null,
    "location_id": "loc_5MHY8nXyvSIqh2",
    "current_stock": -2,
    "action": "",
  },
  {
    "item_variation_id": "itemvar_QQWn8cQxq7TnB6",
    "quantity": null,
    "location_id": "loc_5BpxGVWA9g09vf",
    "current_stock": 0,
    "action": "",
  },
  {
    "item_variation_id": "itemvar_YASfOt2B6B4ixE",
    "quantity": null,
    "location_id": "loc_r91C120vrwlReF",
    "current_stock": 0,
    "action": "",
  }
]
let updated = preItems.map(p => {
  let b = addedItems.find(a => a.location_id === p.location_id && a.item_variation_id === p.item_variation_id);
  return b ? b : p;
});

console.log(updated)
```

Comment: location_id and item_variation_id match with 3 objects  but your function is updating only one

Comment: I updated my answer (needed a fix) and updated the replacement items to make them more obvious in the answer.

Comment: thank you so much, can you pls tell me why mine is not working: 
const findItem = (id) => addedItems.find( itemData => itemData.item_variation_id === id )

const updatedItems = [...preItems.map( item => 
( item.item_variation_id === findItem(item.item_variation_id)?.item_variation_id && 
  item.location_id === findItem(item.item_variation_id)?.location_id 
) ? findItem(item.item_variation_id) : item
)  ]

Comment: b/c you're running 2 finds separate from each other. you want to run them together otherwise you're not making the complete match you're trying to make

Comment: Marked as the answer to my question. Thanks a lot